# Why isn't Firebase In-App Messaging working on physical iOS device?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

Currently, I am trying to get Firebase In-App Messaging to show up on physical devices. It will only show up on the simulator devices for some reason. I am using Xcode(Swift programming language) and my Firebase pods are up to date. Is there some extra code that I need to add to trigger the In-App Messaging?

Does it only work with certain iOS devices?

(This is not Firebase Cloud Messaging)

[image: This is an image of the what I am asking about.]

Comment: in my case, my message pop up but the button click do not go to the URL

Comment: Same problem here, both iOS and Android working only on simulators

Comment: It's very weird that in console i get the log `Running in simulator. Do realtime clearcut uploading.` or `Not running in simulator. Use regular clearcut uploading strategy.` (for physical devices). Maybe there's a different approach for one or other.

Comment: Sometimes i found other log: `No appropriate in-app message detected for display.`
I don't know what it means

Comment: no solution yet ? i have same problem too. Why it's working in simulator but real device just sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

In the "Schedule > Event" setting, it was only `on_foreground`, but adding `app_launch` and `first_open` then works on physical devices.

> FirebaseInAppMessaging 0.11.0

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does not work for me, version 0.11.0 too. By the way the `first_open` event isn't available on in-app messaging.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this problem with react-native-firebase, head here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3467

There are several solutions. The one worked for me: update all react-native-firebase to the latest version (8.2.0 atm)

Answer (score 0):

@IanSp, it should work on physical iOS device for on_foegreound triggering conditions. Did you try to do app fore-ground a couple of times. Sometimes, it would have delay in fetching the messages and therefore it would have to wait for next app foreground timing to get it rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Compare time zones in the test device and campaign. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5250.